# Teechart + Check Box for X - axis Items

Tags: activex, teechart

Can we provide a Check Box for Bottom Axis or X- Axis element like we do for legend. Is there any option in property to select/ deselect X -axis Items at run time.

Thanks
Akshay

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what do you exactly want to hide from the bottom axis. Labels, grid, ticks, minnortiks,... all these elements have a `Visible` property you can set to false when you want. I've added the activex tag. Correct it if that's wrong.

Comment: Actually I have 4 points on x-axis(A1,A2,A3,A4) and added 6 Bar series(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6). I have an option to provide a check box using which we can check or uncheck particular series.Similarly can we have check box for X-axis Values( A1,A2,A3,A4) using which we can hide the complete 6 series data for that point

Comment: How are you adding those "values" in the x-axis? If they are custom labels, you should clear the list of labels and add all them again, except the one you want to hide. And you should find what valueindex corresponds to the value of each series to hide, and set them to null.